# Is the size of a JavaScript object affected by the number of methods in the (GWT) base-class?

Tags: javascript, gwt, memory

I'm currently designing some API that will eventually be used in GWT, and I'm wondering if the number of *methods* in a Java class affects the size of an individual Object instance in JavaScript, after compiling the Java code using GWT.

Expressed another way, if I have an abstract base class with say 200 methods, and then sub-classes that override 2 of those, will the "cost" (memory usage) of those 200 methods be paid once for the application, or once per subclass *instance*?

In Java, the number of methods does not affect the Object size, but I don't know how this works in JavaScript.

The "200" number comes from trying to work-around the lack of Reflection in GWT, but I'd still be interested in the answer even if there was a way to get "fake reflection".

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of question, there will not be an answer on Stackoverflow that beats your own experiments:

Write a class with 200 methods, then write one that subclasses it and overrides 2 methods. Compare JS code sizes to get a basic idea (though this is not the same as instance sizes). Use the [Compile Report](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html) to get a better understanding. Then try compiling with [style PRETTY or DETAILED](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#Why_is_my_GWT-generated_JavaScript_gibberish?), open the result in an editor, and verify if the generated code reuses methods or not. (Maybe also try it in OBFUSCATED mode to be sure).

Or, instantiate lots of objects, and inspect memory usage (several browsers offer tools, e.g. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling)

Generally, make sure that your methods do get called at all - otherwise, the compiler will optimize them away.

Comment: I had no idea how to "inspect memory usage" in JS, which was an important reason why I asked instead of trying.